# How can i put a JSON Array in Angular 9 to the backend (Spring Boot) with a many to many relation?

Tags: mysql, angular, spring-boot, rest

I haven't found a solution for weeks! I hope someone has a good approach.
How can i put a JSON Array in Angular to the backend (Spring Boot) with a many to many relation?
And how do i send this request in my html from-group with an input tag?

In Postman the PUT Request works:
PUT http://localhost:8081/api/employee/12345

```
{"accounts":[{
        "acc_id": 123,
        "emp_id": 12345    
    }]}
```

Backend:

//Controller

```
@PutMapping(Constant.EMPLOYEE + "/{id}")
public ResponseEntity<Employee> updateEmployee(@PathVariable(value = "id") Long employeeId,
            @Valid @RequestBody Employee employeeDetails) throws ResourceNotFoundException {
        Employee employee = employeeRepository.findById(employeeId)
                .orElseThrow(() -> new ResourceNotFoundException("Employee not found for this id ::" + employeeId));

    if (employeeDetails.getFirst_name() != null) {
        employee.setFirst_name(employeeDetails.getFirst_name());
    }
    if (employeeDetails.getLast_name() != null) {
        employee.setLast_name(employeeDetails.getLast_name());
    }
    if (employeeDetails.getStreet() != null) {
        employee.setStreet(employeeDetails.getStreet());
    }
    if (employeeDetails.getStreet_nr() != null) {
        employee.setStreet_nr(employeeDetails.getStreet_nr());
    }
    if (employeeDetails.getCity_id() != null) {
        employee.setCity_id(employeeDetails.getCity_id());
    }
    if (employeeDetails.getEmail() != null) {
        employee.setEmail(employeeDetails.getEmail());
    }
    if (employeeDetails.getDep_id() != null) {
        employee.setDep_id(employeeDetails.getDep_id());
    }
    if (employeeDetails.getBookings() != null) {
        employee.setBookings(employeeDetails.getBookings());
    }
    if (employeeDetails.getAccounts() != null) {
        employee.setAccounts(employeeDetails.getAccounts());
    }
    if (employeeDetails.getLicences() != null) {
        employee.setLicences(employeeDetails.getLicences());
    }

    final Employee updateEmployee = employeeRepository.save(employee);

    return ResponseEntity.ok(updateEmployee);
}
```

}

// Entity Employee

```
@ManyToMany(cascade = { CascadeType.MERGE })
@JoinTable(name = Constant.ACC_EMP, joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = Constant.EMP_ID, referencedColumnName = Constant.EMP_ID), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = Constant.ACC_ID, referencedColumnName = Constant.ACC_ID), uniqueConstraints = {
            @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = { Constant.EMP_ID, Constant.ACC_ID }) })
    @JsonBackReference(value = Constant.ACC_EMP)
    private Set<BankAccount> accounts;
```

// Entity Accounts

```
@ManyToMany(cascade = { CascadeType.MERGE })
@JoinTable(name = Constant.ACC_EMP, joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = Constant.ACC_ID, referencedColumnName = Constant.ACC_ID), inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = Constant.EMP_ID, referencedColumnName = Constant.EMP_ID), uniqueConstraints = {
            @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = { Constant.ACC_ID, Constant.EMP_ID }) })
    @JsonBackReference(value = Constant.EMPLOYEE)
    private Set<Employee> employees;
```

Frontend:

```
export class Employee{
    emp_id: number;
    first_name: string;
    last_name: string;
    street: string;
    street_nr: string;
    city_id: number;
    email: string;
    dep_id: number;
    active: boolean;
    
   accounts: [{
       emp_id: number;
       acc_id: number;
    }];
```

employee.service.ts with simple PUT Request:

```
  updateEmployeeData(id: number, value: any): Observable<Object> {
    return this.httpClient.put(`${this.baseURL + this.empURL}/${id}`, value);
  }
```

How can I put the Array from accounts?

This ist the employee-uptdate.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Employee } from '../model/employee';
import { ActivatedRoute, Router } from '@angular/router';
import { EmployeeService } from '../employee.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-employee-update',
  templateUrl: './employee-update.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./employee-update.component.css']
})
export class EmployeeUpdateComponent implements OnInit {

  id: number;
  employee: Employee;

  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute,private router: Router,
    private employeeService: EmployeeService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.employee = new Employee();

    this.id = this.route.snapshot.params['id'];
    
    this.employeeService.getEmployee(this.id)
      .subscribe(data => {
        console.log(data)
        this.employee = data;
      }, error => console.log(error));
  }

  updateEmployee() {
    this.employeeService.updateEmployeeData(this.id, this.employee)
      .subscribe(data => console.log(data), error => console.log(error));
    this.employee = new Employee();
    this.gotoList();
  }

  onSubmit() {
    this.updateEmployee(); 
  }

  gotoList() {
    this.router.navigate(['/employees']);
  }

}
```

Image from the example tables:
[Image Tables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XVQyZ.png)

Thank you!

Comment: I think you question is only about how to send data.  Have you sure that your employee object has values on `updateEmployee` call. Please ensure that doing a console.log or something.

Comment: Do you have content-type header set to application/json in frontend service.ts?

Comment: I can send data to the restapi. That's working. I have a few too many relationships, so I'm trying to find a solution for how to fill the help table.

Comment: e.g. post data to employee and account table works. But how can i merge this in emp_acc table ?

Comment: If you can `CascadeType.ALL` or `CascadeType.PERSIST` and `CascadeType.MERGE`, should work.